# Datastore: FailedPrecondition: 400 The query requires an ASC or DESC index for kind transcription and property status

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

According to https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datastore/latest/queries#class-googleclouddatastorequerypropertyfilterpropertyname-operator-value
I should be able to run the following query

```
q = client.query(kind='transcription')
result = list(q.add_filter(filter=query.PropertyFilter("status", "=", "IN_PROCESS")).fetch())
print(result)
```

However, when I run I got

```
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 The query requires an ASC or DESC index for kind transcription and property status. Please use the gcloud CLI to remove the single-property index exemption for this property.
```

When I checked the documentation, I found that I should create an index first, using 1 field filter to perform a query my index looks like this

```
indexes:

- kind: transcription
  properties:
  - name: status
```

When I run `gcloud datastore indexes create index.yaml` I got

```
ERROR: (gcloud.datastore.indexes.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This index:
Datastore index on 'transcription' for (status ASC)
is not necessary, since single-property indexes are built in. Please remove it from your index file and upgrade to the latest version of the SDK, if you haven't already.
```

It looks like for queries using 1 field filter, no index is required. But why I still got the error.

Comment: Have you checked what mode your database is in (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/databases/describe).  It's likely your database is not in Datastore mode.

Comment: you are right. i just solved it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your database is in the wrong mode.
You can see the mode with the gcloud command (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/databases/describe). To use the Datastore APIs, you need to be in Firestore in Datastore mode.